# Decimal right cyclic shift in cpp

Tags: c++, binary, decimal, bit-shift, cyclic

I need to do so called "decimal right cyclic shift". For example, if input is `8652` output will be `2865`.

Is there a way to do this operation in CPP without converting to strings and string operations? Just using arithmetic operations, loops and converting to binary.

Comment: You can search *reverse a integer in c++* and get all sorts of answers.

Comment: Do the operations in `<cmath>` count as arithmetic operations to you?

Answer (score 2):

If number of digits in number is strictly 4, you can do:

```
int src = 1234;

int dest = (src / 10) + (src % 10) * 1000;
```

Here, if `src` is having `0` at end, it would get `dest` to be 3 digit. You need to handle that.

For other lengths, you need to adjust the code appropriately.

Comment: I would make `1000` as a named variable/constant instead of magic number and mention that it needs to be changed for other digit numbers

Comment: I agree with you. I gave very basic code for understanding. I would prefer `constexpr` ;)

Comment: Should it be (src/10) + (src%10)*1000

Comment: @Slava, I've edited the question after cup's suggestion. Ignore the missing parenthesis in my code.

Comment: Actually there are no missing parenthesis, none of them are required in this case. But I deleted my previous comment as I by mistake though that @cup suggested to add only parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it can be done in easy and fast way like this for any int number:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int concatenate (int x, int y)
{
        int pow = 10;
        while (y >= pow)
            pow *= 10;
        return x * pow + y;
}

int main()
{

        int rpm = 8652;

        // Cyclic Right Shift
        int lastDigit = rpm % 10;  //getting the last digit
        int otherDigits = (rpm - lastDigit)/10; //rest of the digits
        int CRS = concatenate(lastDigit, otherDigits); //concatenation
}
```

Comment: You are missing type for `rpm`. `rpm - lastDigit` is completely redundant. Your logic will eventually break wit any number that has 0 in middle.

Comment: Thanks for missing type. rpm - lastDigit Is totally needed here. Slava, I tested this with all positions of 0 and it works perfect. If you disagree, put this code in a compiler and run it.

Comment: `rpm - lastDigit` is redundant, just remove it and there will be no difference. And try to rotate number with 0 multiple times and you will see the issue.

Comment: Well, if you remove rpm - lastDigit the logic will brake with 0. If you keep it, it will work with 0, soooo

Comment: It will work exactly the same with `rpm / 10` instead of `( rpm - lastDigit ) / 10`, what 0 you mentioned I have no idea

Comment: As for problem with middle 0. Proper cyclic right shift algo for a given number with N digits should give you the same number after N iterations if called in a loop. Try to call your algo 3 times for number `120` and see if you get the same number `120` at the end.

Comment: There is no need in loop. I took the last digit and put it in front of the rest left digits. Easy!

Comment: It is not question of need. Apply same function 3 times over number 120, proper cyclic algo should get back to 120, your will not.

Comment: Of course not. You'll get 012 which is equal to 12 in integers. But here this is acceptable, cos I work with integers specifically.

Comment: I do not know what "here" means and why it is acceptable, but it is doable with integers to process that value properly. Even if you have requirements that allows your behavior value of such solution for everybody is questionable.

Comment: "here" means "in contexts of this task". I work with integers. If you wont 0 at the beginning of the number, which is makes no sense, go work with strings. It is questionable only for you. Everybody else accept it.

Comment: According to score of your answer nobody accepts it. About strings and other BS, Ajay gave the answer that works with integers and handles 0s properly.